# What happens to an object created and stored in a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Given

```
function Foo(){
   this.name = "foo"
}

Foo.prototype.hello = function(){
   alert("Hello");
}

function bar(){
  var foo = new Foo();
  foo.hello();
}
```

What will happen to variable foo? Will it get garbage collected?

Comment: It only last in `bar`, so can be collected once `bar` complete execution, there's no other reference pointing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many types of algorithm are used for garbage collection... according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) . In the above case, `foo`'s scope is only inside `bar`. So, it will be garbage collected as soon as the function `bar` returns.

**Reference-counting garbage collection**

> This is the most naive garbage collection algorithm. This algorithm
>   reduces the definition of "an object is not needed anymore" to "an
>   object has no other object referencing to it". An object is considered
>   garbage collectable if there is zero reference pointing at this
>   object.

**Mark-and-sweep algorithm**

> This algorithm reduces the definition of "an object is not needed
>   anymore" to "an object is unreachable".
>
> This algorithm assumes the knowledge of a set of objects called roots
>   (In JavaScript, the root is the global object). Periodically, the
>   garbage-collector will start from these roots, find all objects that
>   are referenced from these roots, then all objects referenced from
>   these, etc. Starting from the roots, the garbage collector will thus
>   find all reachable objects and collect all non-reachable objects.

`foo` is satisfying both of the algorithms to be garbage collected